# Select dropdown options in an Iframe moves top/bottom when parent page is scrolled just before opening select dropdown

Tags: select, iframe, scroll

I have select element in Iframe , if i click on select dropdown for first time it opens as expected.
Then, i scroll parent page, after clicking on select dropdown in iframe dropdown options moved top/bottom.

This issue is reproducible on chromium browsers only. It works well on firefox.

I tried position: fixed css.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.